# cross Validation in matlab

Tags: matlab, cross-validation

I have read in the documentation of [crossval](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/crossval.html?refresh=true) is that `mcr = crossval('mcr',X,y,'Predfun',predfun)` function in matlab  calculate the misclassification rate, But if it's apply with 10-fold cross-validation, then we will have 10 different values for misclassification, since we done 10 testing, and each testing produce a result, but the value `mcr` is single or scalar , So does it take the average misclassification rates or it's take the minimum..etc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The average misclassification rate (across all folds and all monte-carlo repartitions) is used. The following line of `crossval` demonstrates the calculation of the average loss -

```
loss = sum(loss)/ (mcreps * sum(cvp.TestSize));
```

where `loss` is initially a vector of losses for each cross-validation fold and each repartition, `mcreps` is the number of repartitions and `sum(cvp.TestSize)` is the total size of the cross-validation test sets.

This is used for both the MSE (mean-squared error) and MCR loss functions.

Comment: Do you have an idea, if there is away to get the best accuracy (or the minimum misclassification )among those k-fold cross validation?

Comment: Well, you could copy the code of `crossval` and change that line to `loss = min(loss)` but I have no idea why you would want the *minimum* misclassification rate (since the purpose of cross-validation is normally to tell you something about your *average* generalization error).

Comment: Is the scientific approach(i.s The accuracy measured in papers) takes the Average misclassification rate as a standard measure of the accuracy?
 I want to take the best classification accuracy in my final results(I don't know how much this thing is scientifically correct)